# Deleting a specific object from core data

Tags: ios, core-data, delete-row

I have a UITableView that contains Core Data objects. When you click on a row, you get taken to another view controller with an option to delete the image among other things. How would I delete a specific object core data based on the row I selected. So say I would selected an image and then clicked the delete button in the presented view controller, it would delete the image I selected only.

EDIT added code for the delete in DetailedViewController

```
NSError *error = nil; 
[self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:self.managedObject]; 

// REMOVE THIS LINE NO NEED TO CALL SAVE TWICE
//[self.managedObjectContext save:&error]; 

if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) { 
NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]); 
abort(); 
} else { 
NSLog(@"Video and Photo Deleted"); 
}
```

Comment: Show the code are you using to populate the UITableView with data and how you are passing the object to the detailed view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you would use something like this if you were deleting in the UITableView and assuming you are using a fetchedResultsController.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView == self.tableView) {
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
           NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
           [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

        }
    }
}
```

However if you are in some detailedViewController then assuming you passed the managedObjectContext and the managedObject to this detailedViewController (self) you would just use this.  Once again assuming you are using fetchedResultsController in conjunction with the UITableView so deletes are correctly reflected in the UITableView.

```
   [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:self.managedObject];
```

You can pass these to the detailedViewController by creating properties and setting the properties like so

```
@interface DetailedViewController: UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObject *detailItem;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

@end
```

and after creating the detailedViewController set the properties as shown below

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSManagedObject *object = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Code to create detailed view and set properties
     DetailedViewController *detailedViewController = [DetailedViewController alloc] ...;
     detailedViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
     detailedViewController.managedObject = object;

     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: so what would I have managedObject be set to, would this be the name of the entity or managedObjectContext?

Comment: Just updated the answer to show how you would retrieve the object assuming you are using a fetchedResultsController.

Comment: Sounds like you need to read up a bit on Core Data, NSFetchedResultsController and UITableView integration :-)

Comment: Is there and error message like "if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {  NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);" but for deleting?

Comment: You need to save to commit the delete so just call save and check for errors after the delete.  The same code you have in your comment.

Comment: So after implementing all of this and saving, it is not saving after the deletion. This is the code I am using to delete in DetailViewController - "NSError *error = nil;
        
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:self.managedObject];
        [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
        
        if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Video and Photo Deleted");
        }"

Comment: put this code in your question so its readable and post the error message you get when saving.  Also post details of the model because if you have referential integrity issues as a result of the delete then the save will fail

Comment: Not sure why you are calling `save` twice, but remove the first one. See my addition to your original question